# How do I preserve a polygon while performing 2D meshing in CGAL?

Tags: polygon, mesh, cgal, triangulation

I would like to create a 2D triangle mesh (possibly Delaunay) between two polygons (say inner and outer polygons). My requirement is that no new nodes be inserted on the inner polygon, or I would like the inner polygon to be preserved. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, it seems you need a constrained Delaunay triangulation. See this [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title29).

Comment: I would like to have the interior region be meshed at a smaller mesh size, the outer polygon can be modified, but the inner polygon to remain fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A [conforming triangulation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html) in CGAL does what you need. You have to give it the outline of your two polygons and set a seed point in the region that you want to preserve. Regions containing seed points will be triangulated but not meshed (see the documentation that I linked above for an example of exactly this behaviour).

You can also use the `is_in_domain()` function to check if a face is in the meshed region. In this way you can ignore the faces in the inner polygon and use your existing triangulation instead of them.